# Custom jasmine matchers and promises

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, promise, protractor

**The Story:**

We've been using a custom jasmine matcher to expect *an element to have a hand/pointer cursor*:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toHaveHandCursor: function() {
            return {
                compare: function(actual) {
                    return {
                        pass: actual.getCssValue("cursor").then(function(cursor) {
                            return cursor === "pointer";
                        })
                    };
                }
            };
        },
    });
});
```

It works great and makes the tests readable:

```
expect(queuePage.sortByButton).toHaveHandCursor();
```

**The problem:**

When the expectation fails, currently we get a completely unreadable huge chunk of red text on the console in a form:

> - Expected ElementFinder({ ptor_: Protractor({ getProcessedConfig: Function, forkNewDriverInstance: Function, restart: Function,
>     controlFlow: Function, schedule: Function, setFileDetector: Function,
>     getSession: Function, getCapabilities: Function, quit: Function,
>     actions: Function, touchActions: Function, executeScript: Function,
>     executeAsyncScript: Function, call: Function, wait: Function, sleep:
>     Function, getWindowHandle: Function, getAllWindowHandles: Function,
>     getPageSource: Function, close: Function, getCurrentUrl: Function,
>     getTitle: Function, findElementInternal_: Function,
>     findElementsInternal_ ... 10 minutes of scrolling ... , click:
>     Function, sendKeys: Function, getTagName: Function, getCssValue:
>     Function, getAttribute: Function, getText: Function, getSize:
>     Function, getLocation: Function, isEnabled: Function, isSelected:
>     Function, submit: Function, clear: Function, isDisplayed: Function,
>     getOuterHtml: Function, getInnerHtml: Function, getId: Function,
>     getRawId: Function, serialize: Function, takeScreenshot: Function })
>     to have hand cursor.

**The Question:**

Why is it happening?
How can we improve the matcher and output a user-friendly error instead? 
Something like:

```
Expected 'auto' to be equal to 'pointer' cursor value.
```

---

From what I understand, we would need to provide a `message` value for a custom matcher, but I'm not completely sure how to pass an actual element's `cursor` CSS value into the message. Here is what I have so far:

```
toHaveHandCursor: function() {
    return {
        compare: function(actual) {
            return actual.getCssValue("cursor").then(function(cursor) {
                return {
                    pass: cursor === "pointer",
                    message: "Expected '" + cursor + "' to be equal to 'pointer' cursor value."
                };
            });
        }
    };
},
```

I expect this to work, but, for some reason, I see the same error message on the console after a test run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we were getting on the console was the *auto-generated jasmine matcher fail message* which consisted of the [*`ElementFinder`*](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) instance string representation - which is, it appears, quite huge for some reason.

Now, to improve the failing message, we would need to use the `message` key alongside with `pass`. We should though take into account that [`getCssValue()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue) *returns a promise* and it needs to be resolved for an actual `cursor` value to be used in a custom error message:

```
toHaveHandCursor: function() {
    return {
        compare: function(actual) {
            var result = {};

            result.pass = actual.getCssValue("cursor").then(function(cursor) {
                result.message = "Expected '" + cursor + "' to be equal to 'pointer' cursor value.";
                return cursor === "pointer";
            });

            return result;
        }
    };
},
```

Now, if the expectation fails, we get a nice error message:

```
- Expected 'auto' to be equal to 'pointer' cursor value.
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, to set a custom message, you should set the `message` attribute of the returned object.

The message is just a regular string. You can use the value of your `cursor` variable if you put together the result object after your promise has been fulfilled.

See the following example how it could be done:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  jasmine.addMatchers({
    toBeDeactivated: function() {
      return {
        compare: function(account){
          var accountStatusCode = account.get('status').statusCode;
          var result = { pass: accountStatusCode === 5 };
          if(result.pass) {
            result.message =  "Expected account with status code '" + accountStatusCode + " NOT to be deactivated.";
          } else {
            result.message =  "Expected account with status code '" + accountStatusCode + "' to be deactivated.";
          }
          return result;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Source](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/writing-beautiful-specs-jasmine-custom-matchers)

Replacing the `account.get()` with a Promise should be simple.

Comment: Sounds correct in theory, though I have problems using it with a promise. Updated the question with what I have so far. Thanks!

Comment: Made it work, posted as a separate answer. Thanks for the help again.